# Data Security in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transparent-data-encryption, always-encrypted, row-level-security

**How do I store the sensitive information on SQL server?**. We have policy guidelines, `DBA and Development engineers are not allowed to view the data as plain text`.

I am aware of the `encryption` technologies and `data masking` technologies but the problems is, except the person who is directly responsible for the data, no one else can access the data as per the policy.

When developers need to perform some calculation on sensitive information, **how is it possible to do that, without decrypting?** while still allowing SysAdmin users to view the encryption key details? I am sure, I am not the first one to implement this system. **How do I design this solution?** Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

Is it possible to create a **reference column based on the original column** and give it to developer for calculations? In that case, how to avoid direct logics or how to avoid people **reverse engineer** the logic and how is it possible to keep the **encryption / hashing logic away from DBA**.

I am open to any other suggestion or workarounds. Thank you!

Comment: Are the developers working directly on production data or do they have a staging environment?

Comment: As of now, developers are working with sample data on staging environment.

Comment: In that case, have you considered anonmyizing the data before its restored on your staging instance? Restore the DB on an instance you control, anonmyize the columns you need to protect, backup and restore that anonymized database to your staging environment/server.

Comment: The way i see it, the only fully secure way is to keep stuff encrypted on the sql server and only decrypt on payroll computer (using AE or manual encryption scheme). This removes possibility to work with the *real* data by developers, because all other schemes will be breakable with people having access to the sql server, even CLR can be breakpointed on. But this probably also fails since an admin can probably install a keylogger on payroll computer. Plus, you always have the "bus problem", what if payroll guy gets hit by a bus. Probably best bet is to host payroll with some cloud provider

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to encrypt and decrypt in the app, and SQL server will of course have no knowledge that this data was born as anything else. Or, in SQL Server 2016, use Always Encrypted which means that the database API (ODBC, ADO.NET, JDBC...) does the job for you. Regardless of which solution, make sure that the DBA don't have access to the key. And, since the whole point is that the SQL Server never sees the clear-text data, you cannot manipulate using pure T-SQL. (In SQL Server 2019 will will have secure enclaves allowing for the database engine to decrypt the data to allow for things such as rotation of keys, LIKE, BETWEEN etc, but that isn't released yet.)

Comment: The problem with decrypting data in app is, the developer will get access to the key. Our requirement is like, except the person directly responsible for the data, no one else should get access. For example, only Payroll head will have access to salary data and he is the one creating encryption keys. I am not sure, how this can be done, without DBA and how developers will perform calculations on salary data without decrypting.

Comment: @rathishDBA if the developers have no access to the production systems, and they're developing in a staging environment, why would they ever see the real data?

Comment: @rathishDBA in AlwaysEncrypted the person who creates the encryption key does not need to be a developer or DBA.  It can be, say, a Domain Administrator, who creates the Encryption Key and installs it on the Payroll head's PC, who can then use it to encrypt and decrypt the data.  But you can't have the head of Payroll be the only person with a Key, since that person could leave the company.

Comment: @George, there are possibilities, where the developers can get encryption details from the application, even if they are not directly having access to production data. Our requirement does not allow this option.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Our requirement, the development team should be able to work on payroll data, but we cannot expose the salary details to anyone, except payroll team. The example, I stated is, only payroll head will know the key, since he already knows the data. The current options are DBA can secure the data, but the problem is 1) DBA can see the data. 2) developers cannot work on salary data without decrypting. Let me know, if there is better and secure way to handle this.
Even, Domain Admin create key, app can see the plain data. We need to restrict plain data to any other user.

Comment: Read up on Always Encrypted to see if it fits your need.  It's designed for such scenarios.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017